# Flutter, how to call/add/trigger others event inside same bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

Flutter, how to call/add/trigger others event inside same bloc

I want to call refresh event after update database

```
mapEventToA("update database").then -> mapEventToB("refresh")
```

is it possible?

I just already have a refresh event so I want to reuse it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to call an event inside the same BLoC you can use the [add](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Bloc/add.html) method.

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {

 ...

 void _onSomeEvent(SomeEvent event, Emitter<MyState> emit){
   // Some logic
   ...

   // Call an event inside the BLoC
   add(const RefreshEvent());
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I have RefreshEvent1 and RefreshEvent2, I do not want to activate refresh2 until Refresh1 is finished.(await Refresh1 and then Refresh2 triggers) Is it possible? Is it possible to handle all of this in a function _onSomeEvent?