# Flutter Bloc, splitting the logic of an event

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using bloc to do user authentication stuff and I want to split the logic inside one of my events into two events.

The event right now looks like this (simplified).

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc() : super(const AuthStateInit()) {
    on<AuthEvent1>((event, emit) async {
      await function1();

      await function2();

      emit(const AuthStateFinal());
    }
  }
}
```

I want to do something like this.

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc() : super(const AuthStateInit()) {
    on<AuthEvent1>((event, emit) async {
      await function1();

      // Call AuthEvent2

      emit(const AuthState1());
    }

    on<AuthEvent2>((event, emit) async {
      await function2();

      emit(const AuthStateFinal());
    }
  }
}
```

One way I can achive this is: calling AuthEvent2 on my streamListener when it catches AuthState1. But I think this over complicates it (and also if I have multiple streamListener that listens on AuthBloc on my project, I have to modify everyone of them). Can I achive this only moddifying this file?

Answer (score 0):

After searching, I found the solution. This answer was what I needed.

[Flutter, how to call/add/trigger others event inside same bloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71192047/flutter-how-to-call-add-trigger-others-event-inside-same-bloc)

So, the answer to my question:

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc() : super(const AuthStateInit()) {
    on<AuthEvent1>((event, emit) async {
      await function1();

      add(const AuthEvent2);

      emit(const AuthState1()); // this can be moved to the top inside on<AuthEvent2>. It will do the same thing.
    }

    on<AuthEvent2>((event, emit) async {
      await function2();

      emit(const AuthStateFinal());
    }
  }
}
```